# Problem with elasticbeanstalk and a docker image in ecr

Tags: jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ecr

I have a docker image in ECR and I want to deploy with beanstalk. I keep getting

```
 ERROR Failed to authenticate with ECR for registry 'xxxxxx' in 'us-east-2'
```

In my Jenkins I have surrounded my eb commands (in shell with this)

script { withAWS(credentials:'aws-credentials') {

And I have even given this user AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess to see if that helped but it didnt

My Dockerrun.aws.json has this in it

```
 {
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/yyyy:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Confirm that IAM roles are configured properly between Elastic beanstalk and ECR!